# Sum of invoice amount based on currencies in netsuite pdf template

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, saved-searches

I want the sum of invoices based on their currencies in netsuite advanced pdf template.

I am expecting the below result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This would be very similar to the this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013395/does-oracle-netsuite-advanced-pdf-template-have-group-by-and-sum-functions/44030039?noredirect=1#comment134502813_44030039):

```
<#assign seen_currencies = []>
<#list transactions?sort_by('currency') as tran>
    <#assign tranCurrency = tran.currency>
    <#if seen_currencies ?seq_contains(tranCurrency )>
    <#else>
        <#assign seen_currencies  = seen_currencies + [tranCurrency]>
        <#assign currencyTotal = 0>
        <#list transactions?sort_by('trandate') as line>
           <#if tranCurrency == line.currency>
              <#assign currencyTotal = currencyTotal + line.amount>
    <tr>... output the transaction columns</tr>
          </if>
        </#list>
       <tr>... output the currencyTotal </tr>
   </#if>
</#list>
```